# MessageManager messages get lost for registration/login forms

Tags: magento-2.1

Magento version: **2.1.8**, problem occurred also in **2.1.5**

Basically the problem is:

1. I try to create a new account on the default `/customer/account/create/` page
2. I input an email with invalid **TLD (*example@email.invalid*)**
3. the validation throws an exception because it's invalid, it gets caught in `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost.php` and the message is added to `the _$messageManager_`
4. after the redirect there's no messages

Until the return of the *execute* method the message is inside the *$messageManager* but after that it gets lost somewhere because I don't receive it on the frontend.

To try and debug, I injected the messageManager into the Register.php block, created a function to retrieve messages as such

```
public function getMessages()
{
    $messages = array();
    $collection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
    if ($collection && $collection->getItems()) {
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $message) {
            $messages[] = $message->getText();
        }
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

and then I print it in the form (in **register.phtml**)

```
echo print_r($block->getMessages(), true);
```

but it's always an empty array

I am using a custom template, but I also tried with the default one and still same situation and all the backend part is default, so I believe the problem is somewhere in Magento.

I also added

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

to the `customer_account_create.xml` layout, but of course doesn't work if there are no messages. Simply adding this to other pages inside the site works fine

Comment: The error messages should be passed in a cookie with the response. Check there to determine if the issue is server side or in the template/js.

Comment: @Pmclain I just checked and the mage-messages cookie is set a little bit after I submit the form but on the redirect it gets deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was stupid... the theme and parent theme were overriding the **messages.phtml**, I deleted the file in the custom themes and now it works.

I'm still new to Magento and I'm working on an existing project, so I had to dive in. So by learning from my mistake I'd say to disable custom themes in case basic functionality isn't working to check if it's the theme or not